# Unhandled exception at 0x00363A09, Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun

Tags: c++

So honestly I can't tell you whats wrong with this. I've read threads with similar problems but people are dealing with allocation of memory and things and that is waaaaaayyyy above my scope as a programmer so far, and my program does nothing nearly so complicated.

```
int main() {
double input[5] = { 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 4.3, 5.6 };
GradeBook test(sizeof(input), input);


test.bubbleSort();
test.printAll();



return 0;
};
```

These are my private data members

```
const static int gradeBookSize = 6;
int classSize;
double grades[gradeBookSize];
bool insertionSorted = false; //simply for efficency
bool bubbleSorted = false;
```

Constructor for my GradeBook Class

```
GradeBook(int inputSize, double inputGrades[]) {
    classSize = inputSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        grades[i] = (inputGrades[i]);
    }
    for (int i = classSize; i < sizeof(grades); i++) {
        grades[i] = 0;
    }

}
```

And finally the two methods Ive actually used in my main() method

```
void bubbleSort() {
    //sorts grades in descending order using bubblesort algorithm
    bool sorted = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(grades) - 1); i++) {
            if (grades[i] < grades[i + 1]) {
                double tmp = grades[i + 1];
                grades[i + 1] = grades[i];
                grades[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
        bool test = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(grades) - 1; i++) {
            if (grades[i] < grades[i + 1]) test = true;
        }
        sorted = !test;
    }


    bubbleSorted = true;
    insertionSorted = false;
}

void printAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(grades); i++) {
        cout << grades[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

And here we have my debug output, I cannot make heads or tails of this

```
The thread 0x3378 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x0130FC38 in CS260_Project4_James_Casimir.exe:0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003).

CS260_Project4_James_Casimir.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'test' was corrupted.

Unhandled exception at 0x00363A09 in CS260_Project4_James_Casimir.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

Unhandled exception at 0x00363A09 in CS260_Project4_James_Casimir.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

Unhandled exception at 0x00363A09 in CS260_Project4_James_Casimir.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

The program '[7400] CS260_Project4_James_Casimir.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: `sizeof(grades)` -- What do you think this will be?  It won't be what you expect it to be.  As a matter of fact, you use it incorrectly wherever you use it, like `sizeof(input)`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought it was similar to java's .size() function. What does it really do that messes all this up?

Comment: The `sizeof(T)` returns the number of **bytes** that type `T` consists of, not the number of items in an array.   C++ is not Java -- don't try and figure out C++ by using Java as a model.

Comment: @paulMckenzie What should I use to find the size of arrays in that case?

Comment: Arrays are dumb as they know absolutely nothing about their size.  If you want to have something Java-like, you would use `std::array<double, 5>`, which does have a `size()` member function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that you're using `sizeof` incorrectly.  The `sizeof` keyword returns the number of **bytes** the type consists of, not the number of items in the array.

What winds up happening in your code is that instead of the number of items in the array,  you're actually using (in the case of the `grades` array)

`sizeof(double)*6`

which will more than likely be 48 (6 items in the array, each item is 8 bytes).  The problem obviously is that your loops will iterate too many times, causing an out-of-bounds memory access in your array accesses (and as you can see, a crash).

If the type is an array, then the number of items in the `grades` array using `sizeof` would be:

`sizeof(grades) / sizeof(grades[0])`

So it's the number of bytes divided by the number of bytes one entry takes up.

---

If you want something more intuitive than the above, then using `std::array` would give this to you:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

std::array<double, 6> grades;
int main()
{
    std::cout << grades.size();  // will output 6.
}
```